# Rails 3 EachValidator for URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, net-http

I want to create an EachValidator that I can use to test the validity of a given URL. Basically I would like to first test if it matches a URL format. If it appears to be a URL then use Net::HTTP to try and resolve the URL (including following redirects). Has anyone out there already done similar to this and would be willing to share their code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out https://gist.github.com/948880